# ComboxBox in DataGrid not showing List in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox, wpfdatagrid

I have a Datagrid and inside first column I have a ComboxBox which holds list of Fee Types.User will need to select the type of fee and enter amount in the next column which is a textbox.I have binded this with the ObservableCollection but the list is not showing up.This is my xaml,see I have binded a observablecollection 'lstFeeType' which is a list of FeeType e.g Admission,Practicle etc.

```
<DataGrid Name="FTDataGrid" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CanUserAddRows="False" Grid.Row="5" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" Height="120" >

            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Fee Type"  Width="*" >
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Path=FeeTypeCollection}" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1"  Name="cmbFeeType" Width="165" Height="25" SelectedValuePath="Id" DisplayMemberPath="Description" SelectedItem="{Binding FeeType}" SelectedValue="{Binding FeeType}"/>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn>

                <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Amount"  Width="*" >
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <TextBox Name="tbFeeAmount" Height="25" Width="140" Text="{Binding Path=Amount}" />
                          </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn>
                <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="+" Width="Auto" >
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <Button HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Background="#2BB3EE" Foreground="#FFFDFAFA" Width="20" Height="20" Style="{StaticResource GelButton}" Click="AddRow_Click" >+</Button>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn>
                <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="-" Width="Auto" >
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <Button   HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Background="#2BB3EE" Foreground="#FFFDFAFA" Width="20" Height="20" Style="{StaticResource GelButton}">-</Button>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn>


            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
```

Code:

```
ObservableCollection<FeeCollection> _lstFee;
    public AddEditFee()
    {
        _lstFee = new ObservableCollection<FeeCollection>() { new FeeCollection() { FeeTypeCollection = FeeTypeCollection() } };
        InitializeComponent();
        FTDataGrid.ItemsSource = _lstFee;
    }
    private ObservableCollection<Dictionary> FeeTypeCollection()
    {

        ObservableCollection<Dictionary> lstFeeType = new ObservableCollection<Dictionary>() { new Dictionary() { Id = 1, Description = "Admission" },new Dictionary() { Id = 1, Description = "Tution" },new Dictionary() { Id = 1, Description = "Annual" }, new Dictionary() { Id = 1, Description = "Practicle" }};
        return lstFeeType;
    }
    private void Cancel_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.Close();
    }

    private void AddRow_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        _lstFee.Add(new FeeCollection() { FeeTypeCollection = FeeTypeCollection() });

    }

    private void Save_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        int a =FTDataGrid.Items.Count-1;
        FeeCollection docPresObj = new FeeCollection();
        docPresObj = (FeeCollection)(FTDataGrid.Items[a]);
    }
```

Classes:

```
public class Dictionary
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
}
public class FeeCollection
{
   public Dictionary FeeType { get; set; }
   public double Amount { get; set; }
   public ObservableCollection<Dictionary> FeeTypeCollection { get; set; }
}
```

What am I doing wrong,Please guide me.

Comment: Please add comment that shows your property deceleration for lstFeeType (also where you are assigning the object to the property) as well as please make an statement about "what is your datacontext".

Comment: See in code in the second line I have declared a observable collection lstFeeType,and in the constructor AddEditFee of my form I am assigning List to this property from function FeeTypeCollection.I am not sure about datacontext I assigned that lstFeeType to it

Comment: Is there a reason for the "DataContext = lstFeeType;" ? Isn't it the ItemsSource of the Combobox? Anyway my guess would be that since FTDataGrids ItemSource is set to "_lstFee" it can't find "lstFeeType" in FeeCollection (should normally be shown as a binding error). I would try placing "lstFeeType" as a property into the "FeeCollection" class .

Comment: Thanks it sloved my problem.Please add your answer in separate comment so I will mark it as answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess would be that since FTDataGrids ItemSource is set to `_lstFee` it can't find `lstFeeType` in FeeCollection (should normally be shown as a binding error). I would try placing "lstFeeType" as a property into the `FeeCollection` class .